# Show QGIS feature count via console on existing layers

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to make a script that toggles feature count on for all vector layers. I followed the following article: [Show feature count of layer via Python console / PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120257/show-feature-count-of-layer-via-python-console-pyqgis).

Instead of adding new layers with feature count I'd like to switch on GUI feature count on existing layers. I adapted the code in the article so that `myLayer` is substituted with an existing layer that I retrieved by listing the layers.

The new layer made by the unadapted code to myLayerNode:

```
<qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeLayer object at 0x000000001FEC4950>
```

The existing layer after saving it in myLayerNode:

```
 <qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeLayer object at 0x000000001FEC49D8>
```

The new layer feature count can be toggled on/off using:

```
myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
```

To my knowledge this should work but it doesn't...

```
#Make a list of layers
qgis.utils.iface.iface = iface
layers = qgis.utils.iface.iface.legendInterface().layers()

## reference to the layer tree
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

## pick one layer to change featurecount
myLayer = layers[5]
myLayerNode = QgsLayerTreeLayer(myLayer)
#root.insertChildNode(5, myLayerNode)

## set custom property
myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)

myLayerNode.customProperty("showFeatureCount")
## the result is True

myLayerNode.customProperties()
## the result is a list [u'showFeatureCount']
```

Any idears?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not completely sure why your code doesn't work but the following works for me in the **Python console**:

- To see the feature count for a **specific layer**:

  ```
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  for child in root.children():
      if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
          if child.layerName() == "LAYER_NAME":
              child.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
  ```

  [image: Feature count of specific layer]

---

- To see the feature count of **all layers**:

  ```
  root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
  for child in root.children():
      if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
          child.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
  ```

  [image: Feature count of all layers]

Comment: @Hydrographer - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Comment: Great! This worked for me.

Comment: @AmarKamthe - Glad to hear it :)

Comment: for a specific layer if child.layerName() ==  has to be chanced into if child.name() ==