# Update feature count of QGIS Layers using PyQGIS when data source changes

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, feature-count

In QGIS 2.18.19 I have a PostGIS Layer with a rule based render and activated `show feature count`. The feature count does not change automatically when doing some `INSERT`s (or `DELETE`s as well) directly into the layers table in the database (likely same applies when e.g. replacing a source shapefile).

I think that such cases are handled with a `my_layer.dataProvider().forceReload()` and there is a couple of ways as well to repaint the layer in the canvas like `my_layer.triggerRepaint()` or `iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayer()`) and even refresh the layer symbology in the legend (`iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(my_layer.id())`) but in all these *refreshes* there seems to be NO WAY to refresh the feature count.

Exception: I noticed, that over the GUI the only way to refresh feature count reliably for the layer itself and all its style rules is to go to *Layer properties*, set up a feature filter (simple expression `True`) and then reset the filter. By clicking **Ok** or **Apply** feature count refreshes as desired, but I need to do this **programmatically**.

I tried reproducing the feature filter in PyQGIS like

```
my_postgis_layer.setSubsetString('True')
my_postgis_layer.setSubsetString('')
```

with no effect.

After days and nights of reading source codes I was not able to figure out whats updating feature count when pressing **Ok** in the layer properties dialog, perhaps anyone could give me some advice...

Question: How can I generally update/refresh feature count in such case with PyQGIS?

Comment: Maybe this helps [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120257/show-feature-count-of-layer-via-python-console-pyqgis)

Comment: nope, doesn't, since turning on/off feature count in the legend does not refesh/update feature count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge following line sets a new instance of source, name and providerType:

```
selectedLayer.setDataSource(selectedLayer.source(), selectedLayer.name(), selectedLayer.providerType())
```

As a result you get a new feature count as well. It's a good way for refreshing datasources changed outside the QGIS environment.

**EDIT:**
As @Jochen Schwarze mentioned, the count number of categorized styles won't be affected and are still displaying the old count number. As a workaround you can simply copy and paste the style after refreshing the source:

```
iface.actionCopyLayerStyle().trigger()
iface.actionPasteLayerStyle().trigger()
```

Comment: +1 does this also affect feature count in categorized an rule based style?

Comment: That's right. Answer edited.