# Enable 'Show Feature Count' option by default when loading a layer

Tags: qgis, layers, user-interface

Some time ago I was searching for an option to activate the 'Show Feature Count' option by default when I load a layer. I found some solutions like this:

- [Setting QGIS to "show feature count" always when layer is loaded?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318190/setting-qgis-to-show-feature-count-always-when-layer-is-loaded)
- [Show feature count with PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329316/show-feature-count-with-pyqgis-3)

That solutions uses Python code, but maybe there is some option in the advanced configuration of the QGIS interface that allows to activate this option.

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I use 3.22, so I don't have the feature. But [see this pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/48088), it should be there since 3.26, if I got it right.

Comment: The new feature seems to be there in QGIS 3.30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved based on winnewoerp and user30184 comments**:

[image]